# Unable to Update RAW query in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a little complex query to update in my database, hence I use `$this->db->query($sql, array($userId));` to update my table, but the table is not getting updated.

Update query as below:

```
UPDATE users usr1
SET dummy_id= (SELECT concat('D',UPPER(c.flag_lang), LPAD(usr1.id , 7, 0)) new_did FROM country c,desktop d
WHERE
usr1.id=d.user_id
AND d.country_id=c.id
and user_type='dummy')
WHERE usr1.user_type='dummy' and usr1.id = ?
```

If I execute the same above query via MySql client, then my table is getting updated.

However, if I write query in Active record as:

```
$this->db->where('id', $userId);
$this->db->set('dummy_id', 'CUSTOM');
$this->db->update('users');
```

The table does get updated properly, but, since the query is complex I have to go for a RAW query, but somehow it is not working.

Request to assist for the same.

Comment: Print your query using `$this->db->last_query();` and see how codeigniter is interpreting it.

Comment: Hi @mPareek, I tried with checking that too, but that didn't help. :(

Comment: So the results of last query worked in your mysql client but the same query is not working  when executed via script?

Comment: @SharadSoni
share output of $this->db->last_query()